# Wowza: Modifying a Stream as it is playing?

Tags: wowza

It seems like this must be happening in many different contexts such as adding subtitles. What I want to do is grab a frame, change some feature within it and then "put it back" so that the end user sees this change. I think I know how to grab and modify the frame but re-inserting it into the stream I do not see how to do. Would appreciate a link or code.

Answer (score 2):

On a live stream, there are a few things to consider depending on what the end goal might be. If it's true packet / frame level manipulation you would likely need to make the modification and set the output to a new stream (source remains unscathed but new stream has the modification). Modifying the stream inline will be very problematic.

> Packet level modification using IMediaStreamLivePacketNotify

You can implement the IMediaStreamLivePacketNotify interface to handle new packets and modify them as necessary. Example implementation:

```
private class PacketListener implements IMediaStreamLivePacketNotify
{

    @Override
    public void onLivePacket(IMediaStream stream, AMFPacket packet)
    {
        // handle packet modifications 
    }
}
```

Upon modifying the packet you could publish it to a secondary stream that you publish through the Publisher object.

```
Publisher.createInstance(vhost, appName, appInstName);
```

The publisher contains functionality to add A/V data to your new stream:

```
    switch (packet.getType())
    {
    case IVHost.CONTENTTYPE_AUDIO:
        publisher.addAudioData(packet.getData(), packet.getAbsTimecode());
        break;

    case IVHost.CONTENTTYPE_VIDEO:
        publisher.addVideoData(packet.getData(), packet.getAbsTimecode());
        break; 
    case IVHost.CONTENTTYPE_DATA:
    case IVHost.CONTENTTYPE_DATA3:
        publisher.addDataData(packet.getData(), packet.getAbsTimecode());
    }
```

There is similar functionality within the [Duplicate Streams module](https://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?613-How-to-duplicate-streams-to-another-application-instance-(ModuleDuplicateStreams)) for a broader look at this implementation.

> Packet level modification using getPlayPackets()

You could also look at the IMediaStream object and leverage the IMediaStream.getPlayPackets() functionality. Then you can obtain the packets and modify as needed in a corresponding thread that continually processes the inbound stream. Thereafter, you could use the Publisher object to publish the new stream (similar to the above).

> Metadata injection

However, if you are just looking to [inject some metadata](https://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?149-How-to-inject-cue-points-or-metadata) the process becomes much more basic. You can modify the AMFDataList within the source stream to include the new meta information.

> Adding onto the stream

If you are looking to add data onto the inline stream (vs modifying it) you could simply add it via the ImediaStream object:

```
IMediaStream.addAudioData(..)
```

Comment: Does Wowza handle Live vs VOD so differently that code that works for one would not for the other? I am having trouble getting examples provided by Wowza to work and I wonder if in using an mp4 file instead of "live" source like a camera (?) is causing the problem.

Comment: For VOD, you cannot get the play packets.  You may be able to do this for VOD requests would be to modify the source via the mediareader, check out the [link](https://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?177-How-to-select-audio-data-and-or-video-channel-from-a-multi-channel-MP4-file-by-using-IMediaReaderActionNotify) as an example of its usage.